# In JS script, Edge throws error 5002 Function expected on object field declaration

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

In rather simple HTML page I added script. That works perfectly with FF and Chrome and not in Edge or IE. While IE problem I can stand for a while, I would rather find solution for Edge.
Edge throws cited error on that line
 `pageQueryInput: document.getElementById('pageQueryInput'),`

while whole part of code is like that:

````
function renderBooks(){
console.log('render');
console.log(document.getElementById('booksContainer'));
console.log(document.getElementById('pageQueryInput'));
// myPage  creates variable storing some important nodes that are built with HTML (and not rendered by this function )and therefore can be determined immy after load event
const myPage ={ 
    booksContainer: document.getElementById('booksContainer'),
    pageQueryInput: document.getElementById('pageQueryInput'),
    radio:  [...(document.getElementById('radioInputs')).getElementsByTagName('input')],//xxxxxxxxxx
    noBooksScreen: document.getElementById('noBooksModal'),
    noBooksScreenContent: document.getElementById('noBooksModal-content'),
    noBooksScreenCloseButton: document.getElementById('closeNoBooksScreen'),
    form: document.getElementById('queryForm'),
    resetButton: document.getElementById('resetButton'),
    }```

That is just beginning of the function so the main brace is not locked. The code is more than simply. I have found some similar questions but none of such the simply case. Could someone have a look?
````

Comment: Can you post the error and stack trace if any?

Comment: Are you using Internet Explorer (which version) or Edge?

Comment: SCRIPT5002: Function expected

Comment: Does your browser support spread syntax? Try using `Array.from` instead (which you can also polyfill if necessary).

Comment: That is Edge: Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134

Comment: Yes, that must be issue of spread operator, but not only.When rewritten to```radio:(Array.from(document.getElementById('radioInputs'))).getElementsByTagName('input'),``` it tells ```SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagName'```

Comment: Try `Array.from(...)` instead of the spread syntax. See the last comment on this issue: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/18418844/

Comment: Because you're calling `.getElementsByTagName()` on the result of `Array.from(...)`.

Comment: Right, wanted to work to quick. Now it correctly runs (till the next error I see, but as per this one it is solved, great).

Comment: As the current issue is solved by the suggestion given by Bergi and Andreas. I suggest them to post their suggestions as an answer and I want to suggest Kiszuriwalilibori to mark that answer as an accepted answer for this question may help other community members in future in similar kind of issue.Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Clear, I will be glad to mark the answers like that